# PHP ORM Propel where to run?

Tags: php, windows, propel

I have tried so hard to start using Propel, I sat down for 2 hours reading their whole documentation, but it realy doesn't tell you where you run 'propel init' command.

http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html

It says I have to run 'propel init' at the bottom of the page, first step of the easy way? But where? I tried opening cmd on windows in my project root and running it but I get:

```
C:\working_area\mycms>propel init
'propel' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And yes, I have got the library installed:

```
"propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
```

Comment: have you tested your installation?  http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html#testing-propel-installation

Comment: I might suggest avoiding Propel2 since it is no longer maintained. The readme for https://github.com/propelorm/Propel3 says "Version 3 of Propel ORM replaces Propel2, which is not maintained anymore".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slides from a conference presentation [Up and Running with Propel2](http://pencilinthehand.com/wp-content/Propel%20Quickstart%20v13.pdf) detail the process to install this command, and as a bonus, walk you through an example of running the command.

I can answer any question on the slides, since I gave the talk.

Comment: Awesome presentation